# vimscript code to create a new numbered file

Tags: vim

I write a lot of math and physics problems in latex files, which have numbered filenames like `albn002.tex`.

Often, I need to create a new file based on a file I am already editing. For this, I have to save the file under a new name, in the same directory, with the next number for which there exists no file.

Ideal would be a procedure 'saveToNewNumberedFile' so that I could assign it to something like ',stn'

Can this be programmed directly in vimscript?

Comment: Should all numbers at the end of the name be considered up for changing, or only the last digit?

Comment: The script should find the next unused file by counting up the 3digit number at the end of the filename (without the extension)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at my [EditSimilar plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2544). **Edit**: In its latest version 2.30, the `:999SavePlus` command (with a large count) will search for the last existing file within that offset range, and then save the current file with an offset one larger than that.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I had a look at the extension, it's missing the function of finding an unused filename

Comment: Yeah, as I've mentioned, automatically finding the unused number and saving wasn't directly possible. Since this is generally useful functionality, I've extended the plugin. Please check out the latest version.

Comment: Thanks again, I have installed your new version and it gets the job done! I tried to find the code for SavePlus, and wanted to isolate it because I don't need all the other functionality of your plugin. The code seems quite big for the simple task that I want to perform, so I would like to reduce it for my purposes. Could you please point me to the relevant part of the plugin?

Comment: Well, it's not so easy. All those commands are related to each other; that's why they are all part of one plugin. Why don't you just keep them; maybe they turn out helpful some time in the future?! (I use all of them a lot.) Alternatively, you could `:delcommand` those you don't want.

Comment: Too bad, I would have liked to learn from the code. But the new command is really handy to create a new example based on an existing one. Big thanks, cool script!